# How do we add startTime in springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean?

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled, quartz

We need to add the **startTime** for spring quartz scheduler. Lets assume the below bean as CronTriggerFactoryBean. And we need to start the scheduler after 5 days of server starting time.

```
<bean id="sampleBean"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetail">
  <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="beanManager"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="beanMethod"/>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
  </bean>
</property>
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/30 * ? * SUN-FRI"/>
</bean>
```

And above scheduler configuration doesn't start when application server get started. Its running like

Let's assume server start at 12:03 PM.
Scheduler invoking at `12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00` ... respectively.

But what we want is server start at 12:03 PM means the scheduler should run once at the time of server starting and the following time too `12:33, 13:03, 13:33, 14:03` ...

Will it work when we are setting the **startTime** for this bean?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SimpleTriggerFactoryBean` instead of `CronTriggerFactoryBean` and define a trigger like this:

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="10000" />
</bean>
```

This will run the job every 10 seconds with initial delay of 1 second from server start. Now adjust the values as per your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your reply. And where can i restrict the days like SUN-FRI

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible using simple trigger.

Comment: Yeah. The problem will be like we are unable to add the days in SimpleTriggerFactoryBean